# where does a .net Winform's application's app.config file reside..?

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

As per this link we can add  node in app.confi file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

so, where does that file exist? If i have given some exe to some one , can I later give him a app.config and ask them to place in the right location - so, that application functions accordingly..?

My app is C# .net 2.0.

Comment: Your link is a page that talks about version compatibility...

Comment: yes, as mentioned in that link -i want to do this  "To define the specific versions on which your application runs, add one or more <supportedRuntime> elements to your application's configuration file."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same folder as the exe. Note the app.config file should be the same name as the exe with a .config stuck at the end. That is, if you had a program `fooBar.exe`, the config file should be named `fooBar.exe.config`.